# Html.HiddenFor with enum

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following in my view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MeasurementUnitType)
```

MeasurementUnitType is an enum which looks like:

```
public enum MeasurementUnitType
{
    Metric, Imperial
}
```

Whatever happens to that enum on the model, the hidden field is always set to metric.

I did try having an editor template for it:

```
@using Ns.Domain.Models.Enums
@model Ns.Domain.Models.Enums.MeasurementUnitType
@{
    switch (Model)
    {
        case MeasurementUnitType.Metric:
    <text>
    @Html.Hidden("Metric", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue)
    </text>
break;
        case MeasurementUnitType.Imperial:
    <text>
    @Html.Hidden("Imperial", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue)
    </text>
break;
        default:
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

but that would output the hidden field as

```
 <input id="NewTable_MeasurementUnitType_Metric" name="NewTable.MeasurementUnitType.Metric" type="hidden" value="Metric" />
```

or

```
 <input id="NewTable_MeasurementUnitType_Imperial" name="NewTable.MeasurementUnitType.Metric" type="hidden" value="Imperial" />
```

respectively

this wont work as the Id has the actual value of the enum as well as the name of the enum in the Id...

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: For your second example can't you just pass the same value as the first parameter to `Html.Hidden`?  Thus keeping the IDs of the hiddens the same

Comment: yeah - doing that now - that wont fix the issue though will it?

Comment: nope...  didn't work.. headache...

Comment: Yeah it should do - although you might want to use `ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName`

Comment: that worked :) bung it in an answer and i'll mark it as correct for future me's looking for the same answer

Comment: Ah no, sorry - I didn't scroll through your html completely - I see the input name was coming out correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now supported out of the box in mvc5

https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/MVC/EnumSample/

Comment: So, erm. How does this address the issue of the enum value's name being rendered in the hidden field, instead of the underlying integer, which is why he gets the incorrect value back on POST?

Comment: The link is stale. There is no longer anything on that page with an anchor named "Samples/MVC/EnumSample/".

Comment: You can find it here (https://github.com/aspnet/samples/tree/master/samples/aspnet/MVC/EnumSample), but I think it does not address the OP question

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it like this:

```
   @Html.Hidden(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName, 
     ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue)
```

You might then also be able to get away with no switch statement.

You might also have fallen foul of the apparent MVC bug (which isn't), mentioned on another SO, [whereby MVC will use ValueProvider-provided values from a POST request if you re-render the view](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx).

Comment: yup - deleted the switch - working a treat.. simple and clean

Comment: model binder doesn't like it - i think because it submits as just "Imperial" and not "MeasurementunitType.Imperial"... this is another issue though