# Error while creating hidden field for model in ASP.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I m trying to render a hidden field in partial view for model which is an enum

my code is

```
@model App.PrivacyLevelEnum
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m);
```

I have checked Model is not empty but i am getting following error while rendering the view

```
Value cannot be null or empty.\r\nParameter name: name

Stack trace

   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.InputHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, InputType inputType, ModelMetadata metadata, String name, Object value, Boolean useViewData, Boolean isChecked, Boolean setId, Boolean isExplicitValue, String format, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.HiddenHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value, Boolean useViewData, String expression, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.HiddenFor[TModel,TProperty](HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.HiddenFor[TModel,TProperty](HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Profile_PrivacyLevel_cshtml.Execute() in c:\TFS\DEFAULTCOLLECTION\Gac.Hr\Development\Source\Gac.Hr.Web.Html5\Views\Profile\PrivacyLevel.cshtml:line 58
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Profile_ProfileDetailsEditor_cshtml.Execute() in c:\TFS\DEFAULTCOLLECTION\Gac.Hr\Development\Source\Gac.Hr.Web.Html5\Views\Profile\ProfileDetailsEditor.cshtml:line 107
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at GacHrUI.Controllers.ProfileController.StringifyView(String viewName, Object model) in c:\TFS\DEFAULTCOLLECTION\Gac.Hr\Development\Source\Gac.Hr.Web.Html5\Controllers\ProfileController.cs:line 62
   at GacHrUI.Controllers.ProfileController.RenderEditMode() in c:\TFS\DEFAULTCOLLECTION\Gac.Hr\Development\Source\Gac.Hr.Web.Html5\Controllers\ProfileController.cs:line 35
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
```

Quick help will be really appreciated

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: i have put it in the post

Comment: Can't say for sure, but maybe HiddenFor requires a property reference (ex: `HiddenFor(m=>m.MyEnumProp)`)?

Comment: Can you add the definition of your class `App.PrivacyLevelEnum`

Comment: @Zed its an enum having 4 enum values. do you still want to see it?

Comment: Just because it is called `SomethingEnum` it does not mean it is an enum. It should clarify the question.

Comment: [It would not be the same problem?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580964/html-hiddenfor-with-enum

Comment: You need to show your model and the GET method. Your model needs to contain a property for the enum (you cant just have the enum itself as the model)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is not an empty model but an incorrect usage of `HiddenFor` attribute

The signature of a method is :

```
HiddenFor<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>)
```

where `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>` specifies a model property for which you are going to generate a hidden input. This expression looks something like `model => model.Name`. If I make a long story short, this expression is then used to generate `name` and `id` attributes for the generated html input

In your case, the expression that you provide generates an empty name which is invalid. This is the method that throws an exception (from MVC source code):

```
 private static MvcHtmlString InputHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, InputType inputType, ModelMetadata metadata, string name, object value, bool useViewData, bool isChecked, bool setId, bool isExplicitValue, string format, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
        {
            string fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(MvcResources.Common_NullOrEmpty, "name");
            } 
          ... 
         }
```

Now about possible solutions:

1) Decorate your property in model with `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.hiddeninputattribute(v=vs.118).aspx))- this way you wont have to create a partial view at all. Usage:

2) Create an `EditorTemplate`. You can call it `HiddentEnum.cshtml` for 
example (Make sure to store it under `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder):

```
  @model Enum

  @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model)
```

Usage:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TestEnum, templateName: "HiddenEnum")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your model datatype is an enum and not a class with properties, you have to specify a name and id when you use it in your display.

```
@Html.Hidden("privacyLevel", Model, new { @id="privacyLevel"})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the property name:

```
HiddenFor(m => m.yourPorperty)
```

Comment: but i am making a generic control which i can use any where in my app. i need to pass enum as model and does not have any property.

Comment: For that you could define an EditorTemplate and the use it with `EditorFor` wherever you like.